# Tensorboard Scalars Count

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

What is the count shown on the right side of a graph on the tensorboard scalars tab (see 1 on the right side of the attached image).

There are no runs shown for this measure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the amount of summaries grouped under that category when checking the "Split on underscores" option on the upper-left part:

[image]

For example, I have two scalar summaries, one called `losses_per-epoch` and the other called `losses_per-batch`. When checking the "Split on underscores" option both are grouped under the "losses" category, and the count becomes 2:

[image]

Comment: What does the number represent when no grouping is enabled? Does it just show `1` ?

Comment: I have never seen the number change under other circumstances. I'm sorry I can't provide a more accurate answer since I haven't read the code nor found any documentation concerning this.